# Randomize StringList

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

How can I randomize the Strings in the StringList similarly how this online tool works. If anyone is familiar with it, check this: http://textmechanic.co/Randomize-List.html

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Seriously what does this have to do with the question?!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The fixed link is : 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Ah i thought you are sending me to a Fishermans link :)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You are welcome to post your solution. Nobody is holding you down :)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan is there any point in arguing? let it be...

Comment: Page about fishermen? I don't get that.

Comment: Your link in your first comment above. It links to wikipedia/Fisher. Don't be silly, you know it because you've posted the corrected link *after* Santos's response.

Comment: @Golez I didn't post a corrected link. I had not realized my link was eaten. I understand what you are all talking about now.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

One common algorithm to perform a shuffle is the [Fisher-Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) shuffle. This generates uniformly distributed permutations.

To implement on a Delphi `TStrings` object you can use this:

```
procedure Shuffle(Strings: TStrings);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := Strings.Count-1 downto 1 do 
    Strings.Exchange(i, Random(i+1));
end;
```

Now, whilst in theory this will generate uniformly distributed permutations, the actual performance depends heavily on the quality of the random number generator. This is discussed in Knuth's Art of Computer Programming, volume 2, section 3.4.2, Algorithm P.

Further reading:

- [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) (Wikipedia)
- Jeff Attwood's two blog articles on shuffling: [Shuffling](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/shuffling.html) and [The Danger of Naïveté](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/the-danger-of-naivete.html)
- [The intuition behind Fisher-Yates shuffling](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/05/28/the-intuition-behind-fisher-yates-shuffling/) (Eli Bendersky)
- [Art of Computer Programming](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/taocp.html), Donald Knuth, volume 2, section 3.4.2
- [Shuffling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuffling) (Wikipedia)

Comment: Can't we use RandomRange ?

Comment: Yes, Santos, but why bother? Random(i+1) is equivalent to RandomRange(0, i).

Comment: It was @Rob who responded? And I don't understand why you adopt a sarcastic tone towards people that try do things as well as possible, and help you out along the way.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yea however the solution that you provided is almost exact as GolezTrol :)

Comment: Not at all. Golez's code is skewed.  Some permutations are chosen with higher prob than others. I suspect you don't want that.

Comment: @delphirules What is your alternative algorithm that is algorithmically more efficient. Can you do it in fewer than N swaps? Pretty hard to see how that would be possible.

Comment: @david-heffernan i don't know but this site randomize a large list in seconds, i wish to know what is the algotithm used : http://www.randomizelist.com/

Comment: @delphi Define large please. Which algo could do it in fewer than N swaps? And please give some timings for Fisher-Yates.

Comment: @david-heffernan i tested with a list with about 10.000 itens ; it took minutes to finish.

Answer (score 5):

Just loop through the stringlist and give each item an different random place:

```
for i := StringList.Count - 1 downto 1 do
  StringList.Exchange(i, Random(i+1));
```

[edit]
Altered the loop a bit to make the shuffling uniform.

Comment: Yep a true shuffle :) And the most sane one.

Comment: This answer demonstrates one of the Fisher-Yates errors discussed in Wikipedia, in the ["implementation errors"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Implementation_errors) section. Although it still yields a shuffled result, which is all the question asked for, it's not a uniform shuffle algorithm. Quality of the RNG is orthogonal to that issue.

Comment: @RobKennedy Okay. Good to know, and the explanation you point to makes it very clear. I've altered the loop a little. Used downto, because it makes the loop simpler. The `+1` is there to prevent an accidental implementation of Sattolo's algorithm.

Comment: So I deleted all my comments since they are no longer applicable to your answer

Comment: I found a couple more nice posts on this topic: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/shuffling.html http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/the-danger-of-naivete.html

Comment: Thanks, but especially the first link is more applicable to the answer by Trident.

Answer (score -4):

To randomize a `TStrings`, create a comparer from `TComparer` with **random result value**, and sort the `TStrings` with it.

```
/// The Comparer
TMyShuffleComparer= class(TComparer<string>)
public
  function Compare(const Left, Right: string): Integer; override;
end;

/// The randomizer 
function TMyShuffleComparer.Compare(const Left, Right: TCard): Integer;
begin
  // To sort, get a random number for compare result
  Result := Random(100) - 50;
end;

/// How to call the comparer
procedure TMyStrings.Shuffle;
begin
 Sort(TMyShuffleComparer.Create);
end;
```

or to call directly:

```
  /// Shuffle
  MyString.Sort(TMyShuffleComparer.Create);
```

Comment: -1 A sort compare function needs to define a total order. This doesn't. It's a simply terrible idea. I suggest that you delete the answer. Have a read of this, for example: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/10/23/55408.aspx

Comment: Comparison functions that are inconsistent can lead to non-terminating sort functions and buffer overruns. They are not the way to shuffle a list.

Comment: Whilst it is possible to use sorting algos to shuffle, this is not how to do it. Even when you get it right you have much more complex code that is slower than, for example, Fisher-Yates.

Comment: I tested it according to your remarks and I now understand my mistake on the comparer. Trying to reply to the answer, I've fix my own error ;)

Comment: This is a kind of novelty idea, **but**, as @Rob said, your comparing function has to be [**deterministic**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178091.aspx) (disregard SQL flavour), otherwise you end up with poorly shuffled resulting list.

Comment: Also, your selection of random value prefers negative values: [-50, 49]