# Delphi Random Returns Zero on a low range

Tags: delphi

I am using delphi 7 and im trying to shuffle a set of numbers from one list box to another.

02H,02D,02S,02C,03H,03D,03S,03C,10H,10D,10S,10C,11H,11D,11S,11C,20H,20D,20S,20C,30H,30D,30S,30C.

but for some reason, 30C always seems to be last,
when i random 0,2 or 0,1 it seems to always give me 0.

```
procedure TMainForm.btShuffleClick(Sender: TObject);
var I: integer;
begin
    lstShufd.Clear;
    while lstNew.Count <> 0 do
        begin
             Randomize; 
             I:=RandomRange(0,lstNew.Count-1);
             lstShufd.Items.Add(lstNew.Items.Strings[I]);
             lstNew.Items.Delete(I);
        end;
end;
```

Comment: Why are you calling `Randomize` in every loop? It sets the random seed from the clock, so you are probably getting the same value several times. Use it only once in your program.

Comment: For a quick summary of shuffling methods, see also [`Randomize StringList`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14006825/576719).

Comment: I wonder why the so many beginners are calling `Randomize` in the loop...

Comment: @FreeConsulting To get a more random number! Another way is to call random multiple times to get a more random value. But it doesn't work that way.

Comment: @LURD sorry, didn't realized this :o)

Comment: HI all, ive tried randomize outside and inside the loop, it still refuses to shuffle the last number. should i just place the the last number randomly?

Answer (score 6):

You have two errors:

1. You must not call `Randomize` repeatedly in the way you do in the question. Doing so will destroy the distributional properties of your random sequence. Typical usage is to call `Randomize` once at the start of the program.
2. `RandomRange` returns a value `I` in the range `AFrom <= I < ATo`. So you are passing the wrong parameters. Use `RandomRange(0, lstNew.Count)` or even just `Random(lstNew.Count)`.

The second of these errors explains the behaviour that you observe. In your code, by calling `RandomRange(0, lstNew.Count-1)` you get a value in the range `0 <= I < lstNew.Count-1` and so the final item in `lstNew`, that is the item with index `lstNew.Count-1` cannot be chosen until the final iteration of the loop.

The documentation for [`RandomRange`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Math.RandomRange) says:

> ```
> function RandomRange(const AFrom, ATo: Integer): Integer;
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> Returns a random integer from a specified range.
>
> RandomRange returns a random integer from the range that extends
>   between AFrom and ATo (non-inclusive). RandomRange can handle negative
>   ranges (where AFrom is greater than ATo).

Comment: Found a [better documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.Math.RandomRange) "RandomRange returns a random integer from the range that extends between AFrom and ATo (non-inclusive)"

Comment: @some You should always read the actual documentation rather than DelphiBasics which is low quality.

Comment: Well, I guess that it is the equivalent to w3shools, but it was the first result on Google. To my defense it was almost a decade ago that I used Delphi, when it was still owned by Borland. Where is the official documentation now?

Comment: @some, you've linked the official documentation in your comment. It is for Delphi XE5 though, but since there is no official Delphi 7 online help, it is one of "the best" you can link to. As far as I remember, there was (and maybe still is) the online help for Delphi 2009 as the oldest Delphi version online help.

Comment: @TLama When I link to online docs, I remove the version from the URL. That way the link resolves to the latest version, and is not tied forever to XE5.